# Insert drop down menu in LayerControl panel in leaflet

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

Since my last question got answers so fast, and I am lost concerning another problem, even though I didn't have time to check the answers to this last question, I'm asking the other one already.

So, I would like to insert a drop down menu in the Layer control panel in leaflet to manage some buffer area with different distances wich would be triggered for a marker (or a polyline), when I'm clicking on it.

For now I tried to get into leaflet-src.js and modify the LayerControl, but since I don't really know what I'm doing I just mimiced what I saw for the other options (baselayer and overlay). Ideally, I would like to have a dynamic layer with only one buffer drawn at once, only if my layer is checked on in the LayerControl panel, and with the buffer the size according to the selected distance. Here is the piece of code I'm using to illustrate my situation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<head> 
<title>Example</title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.css"/>
<style>

body {
    font-family: Helvetica;
    margin:0;
}

#map{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>

var sites = [
        {'loc':[42.2793869135936,9.53257201027757],'title':'TORRA A I CASELLI'},
        {'loc':[42.2713622720985,9.50678498185463],'title':'TOUR GIANDINELLI'},
        {'loc':[42.641518105666,9.00587322013212],'title':'TOUR DE LOSARI'},];

var map = new L.Map('map');
var osm = map.addLayer(new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'));
map.setView([42.5,9.2210706018535],9);

var marks = new L.LayerGroup();
    for(i in sites) {
        var title = sites[i].title,
            loc = sites[i].loc,
            markersites = new L.Marker(new L.latLng(loc), {title: title});
        markersites.bindPopup('<strong>'+title+'</strong><br>');
        marks.addLayer(markersites);
    }
marks.addTo(map);

// for now it is all good, the next part is where I fail, please notice the extra overlay I put as a comment and which should include my selectable, checkable, dropdown menu

var baseLayers = {
    "OpenStreetMap": osm
};
var overlays = {
    "Sites":marks,
    /*"Distance":...,*/
};


L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays,{collapsed:false, hideSingleBase:true}).addTo(map);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And since I didn't manage to find anything close to what I would like, I can just hope for someone to have an idea (and a better knowledge of web codes) to have anything pointing me in the good direction.

Thanks for your attention.
Cheers,
Guillaume

Comment: I think you'd be better off reading the [Leaflet tutorial on making custom controls](http://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-3-controls.html).

Comment: I'll do that. I'm sorry I asked a question which would find an answer in the tutorial, even though I already tried to look into it but didn't figure I could do something with it, likely due to my lack of experience in web coding. Thank you for your attention.